# Filtering SQL data in php / js table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datatable

I am trying to use js to filter the data that has been extracted into the table via php.

The page in which I am trying to get this working on is below:
http://awaluminium.com/orcadev-v2/layout1/order-list.php

As you can see the top example works fine and allows you to filter the data using multiple search criteria. However when you try and filter the bottom example it simply doesn't do anything.

The code for the table at the bottom is below:

```
<div class="portlet light portlet-fit bordered calendar">                               
                            <div class="portlet-body">
                                <div class="row">                                        
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="panel">
                                    <div class="panel-header panel-controls">
                                      <h3><i class="icon-bulb"></i>All Orders</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-content">
                                    <?php

                                    //create a database connection
                                    mysql_connect("localhost","#","#") or die("Error:".mysqlerror());
                                    //select database
                                    mysql_select_db("#");

                                    ?>
                                    <table class="table table-hover table-dynamic filter-head">
                                    <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Rendering engine</th>
                                        <th>Browser</th>                                            
                                      </tr>
                                    </thead>                                    
                                     <?php

                                    //create the query
                                    $result = mysql_query("select * from cemarking");

                                    //return the array and loop through each row
                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                    {
                                    ?>
                                       <tr class="LightboxTrigger" data-lightboxid="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>">
                                        <td style='display:none'><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>                  
                                        <td><?php print $row['jobnumber'];?></td>                   
                                        <td><?php print $row['system'];?></a></td>



                                      </tr>

                                    <?php 
                                    } 

                                    ?>
                                    </table>

                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      </div>
```

Can anyone see why the data will not filter in the bottom table?

EDIT:Please find JS in question below.

```
<script src="http://www.awaluminium.com/orcadev-v2/assets/global/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> <!-- Tables Filtering, Sorting & Editing -->
<script src="http://www.awaluminium.com/orcadev-v2/assets/global/js/pages/table_dynamic.js"></script>
```

Comment: You *should* switch from `mysql_*` as it has been [officially](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) deprecated. Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) **with** [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Where be the JavaScript?

Comment: Your question suggests this is a javascript problem but you have not posted any

Comment: I have edited and provided links to the js

Comment: Why not filtering directly in the SQL-Query with a `WHERE` part? This reduces the network-load as well..